# Merge by distance does smth weird

Tags: mesh

I accidently duplicated my mesh and can't go back anymore. When I merge by distance(remove doubles) it works but this happens, help

[image: smth weird happens when I merge by distance]

ps I tried changing merge distance, didn't work

Comment: Share your file, I'll take a look... https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: You can select one copy of the duplicated mesh when you hover the mouse over the mesh and press key L. This will execute the *Selected Linked* operation and select the verts. But there might be more wrong that causes these shading issues.

Comment: Do you have a solifidy modifier ? Looks like inverted normals. When in edit mode select everything and SHIFT + N

Comment: since the solution wasn't connected directly to my question should I delete the whole thing? (I'm a new user)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solidify modifier was inverted.
SHIFT + N in edit mode while everything selected fixed the problem.

thx @Gorgious

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, **[accept the answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)** that you found most helpful. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/121804)

Comment: The thing I found useful is not an answer, it's a comment to my post, I can't accept it...or can I?

Comment: @feik It's alright, I think you have to wait a little bit before you can accept your own answer. Cheers